# Esay way to calculate $\int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy = \frac{y}{1+y^2}+C$

Tags: calculus

We know $\int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy = \frac{y}{1+y^2}+C$, and I can calculate by $y=\tan \theta$, but I think it is a bit of cumbersome.  Is there some easy way to calculate it? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure this is more elegant, but how about partial fractions?

Comment: @avs I have tried partial fraction, it is difficult than $y=\tan \theta$

Comment: By simply guessing: judging from the denominator the solution will probably be of the form $\frac{ay+b}{1+y^2}+c\log(1+y^2)$. Derive this term and see if some triple $a,b,c$ fits. It only takes a few seconds to do, and has a good chance to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a stupid one..

$\int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy\\
\int \frac{1}{1+y^2}-\frac{2y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy$

we know that
$\int \frac{1}{1+y^2} = tan^{-1} y + c$ but what about the other term?

$-\int \frac{y(2y)}{(1+y^2)^2} dy\\
u = y, dv = \frac{2y}{(1+y^2)^2} dy\\
du = dy, v =-\frac{1}{(1+y^2)}\\
\frac {y}{1+y^2} - \int \frac {1}{(1+y^2)} dy$

So,

$\int \frac{1}{1+y^2}-\frac{2y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy = \int \frac {1}{(1+y^2)} dy + \frac {y}{1+y^2} - \int \frac {1}{(1+y^2)} dy$

$\frac {y}{1+y^2} + c$

Answer (score 2):

*A small trick without any integration.*

Because of the square in denominator, you can assume that $$\int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy = \frac{P_n(y)}{1+y^2}$$ where $P_n(y)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Differentiate both sides to get $$\frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2}=\frac{\left(y^2+1\right) P_n'(y)-2 y P_n(y)}{\left(1+y^2\right)^2}$$ In the rhs, the degree of the numerator is $2+(n-1)=1+n$; since it is $2$ in the lhs, then $n=1$.

So, now, we know that $P_1(y)=a+b y$; so $$\frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2}=\frac{\left(y^2+1\right) b-2 y (a+by)}{\left(1+y^2\right)^2}=\frac{b-2ay-by^2}{\left(1+y^2\right)^2}$$ Now, identify to get $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Divide throughout the fraction by $y^2$ to obtain:

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{\frac{1}{y^2} -1}{\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2} \text{d}y = \int \frac{-\text{d}\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)}{\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2}$$

Which yields immediately to the reverse chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

A substitution of 1+y^2 or such is tempting but the derivative produces a y term which needs removal by trig substitution. Thus a substitution in both y^2 and y is needed. The only way I can see is this substitution:

$$ u= \frac {y}{1+y^2} \Rightarrow  \frac {du}{dx}= \frac {1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} \\ \therefore I=\int \frac {du}{dx}dx =\int du = u+C=\frac {y}{1+y^2}+C$$

But is substituting the answer, which is trivial as it works for any integral. The $\tan \theta $ substitution is cumbersome but the only solution I can see.

Comment: this answer is bad, because when I calculate it I do not know the right side of it.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: I mean if you do not know the right side of it, can you figure out this way?

Comment: By the reasoning I used at  the beginning, if you were VERY clever and/or had a lot of integration experience, you would know you would need a sub of the form 1/(1+y^2) with a y term in it as well and could go through possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=\tan u$ we have
$$\int \frac{1-y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} dy=\int\frac{1-\tan^2u}{1+\tan^2 u}du=\int \cos 2u\,du=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2u+C= \frac{\tan u}{1+\tan^2 u}+C$$

Comment: please read question first

Comment: Yes. but it is easy

Comment: Indeed, I showed the simplicity of this way.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int{1 - y^{2} \over \pars{1 + y^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd y} & =
\int{\pars{1 + y^{2}} - 2y^{2} \over \pars{1+y^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd y =
{\Huge\int}{\ds{\totald{y}{y}\pars{1 + y^{2}} - \totald{\pars{1 + y^{2}}}{y}\,y} \over \ds{\pars{1 + y^{2}}^{2}}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\int\dd\pars{y \over 1 + y^{2}} =
\color{#f00}{y \over 1 + y^{2}} + \pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}
\end{align}